# SSRS report not returning all records while running from rdl

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, rdl

I am developing a SSRS report using ReportBuilder2012 v3. I have a stored proc which is based on a dynamic sql and has 10 parameters. All my datasets are pulling data from the stored proc. When I execute the stored proc in ssms I get the desired no of records say 60 . But when I run it from rdl i will only 40 records on one page and 20 records missing from rdl. I have gone through lot of posts on this and have tried setting the DisplayElementOutput to "Output" for each textbox from "Auto" still no luck. It's a simple report without any table groupings. I created a new report from scratch but still no luck. I am stuck with it since yesterday and couldn't figure out why is this happening.

Any pointers would be really helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: Try running SQL Server Profiler and execute the report to see the query for stored procedure and the parameters..

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be that I was using some kind of filter in one of my data set queries and it was restricting the results to be 39. I removed that and now it shows exactly 60 records.